# How can I filter nested array object fields when querying Dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb item which looks like:

```
{
 "taxAmounts": [
  {
   "amount": {
    "currency": "AUD",
    "value": 209
   },
   "name": "GST"
  }
 ]
}
```

I am looking for a filter to filter on the `name` field of `taxAmounts`. I have tired:

```
--filter-expression "contains (taxAmounts.#name, :gst)"
--expression-attribute-values '{":gst":{"M": { "name": {"S":  "GST"}}}}'
-expression-attribute-names '{"#name": "name"}'
```

but it doesn't return any item. What is the right way to filter them?
but

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`taxAmounts` is a list, so you need `[n]` to select the n-th element. `"GST"` is a string, so no need to bother about the Map data type.

Try this:

```
--filter-expression "contains (taxAmounts[0].#name, :gst)"
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":gst": { "S": "GST" }'
--expression-attribute-names '{"#name": "name"}'
```

### EDIT

Editing based on your and Hunterhacker's comment. If you want to search the entire list instead of only the n-th element, you may consider re-structuring your list into a map. Example:

```
{
  "taxAmounts": {
    "GST" : {
      "amount": {
        "currency": "AUD",
        "value": 209
      }
    },
    "TAX2": {...},
    ...
  }
}
```

You can then search using the `attribute_exists` function.

```
FilterExpression = 'attribute_exists(#0.#1)',
ExpressionAttributeNames = {
    "#0": "taxAmounts",
    "#1": "GST"
}
```

Speaking of re-structuring, `scan` is an expensive operation in the first place. Filter does not help to reduce the scanned items, as it only filters the result *after the scan* and before returning the response. Consider having a second table, say `taxAmounts`, having `GST`, `TAX2`, etc. as the Sort Key.

Comment: Does it mean only search the nth element? I'd like to search any element inside the array to match the attribute value.

Comment: Convert your list to a map, using each name as the key. Then it's easy to query for and also kinda more elegant besides.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao edited the answer based on this requirement. To confirm my understanding, seems you want to return the item as long as one of the element inside the array matches.